# Beautiful soup extracting specific columns

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

slowly learning python and beautifulsoupbut been stumped by this.

i am trying to extract the 1st and 4th columns of data from the following layout (reduced in size)
http://pastebin.com/bTruubrn

the file is stored locally and at present i have a patchwork of code from other similar issues that i cannot get to work

```
for row in soup.find('table')[0]body.findall('tr'):
first_column = row.findAll('td')[0].contents
third_column = row.findAll('td')[3].contents
print (first_column, third_column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Beautiful Soup's [support for CSS selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
first_column = soup.select('table tr td:nth-of-type(1)')
fourth_column = soup.select('table tr td:nth-of-type(4)')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things that are wrong with your code. This line:

```
soup.find('table')[0]body.findall('tr'):
```

makes no sense. When you use `find` it returns a single BS object. You can not access elements with index on a single object. And wherever you use `findAll`, it returns a list of BS objects. Which means you have to loop over it to get individual elements. That is the reason the body of your for loop won't work as expected.

Below is the code that gets you what you want:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_file = open('html_file')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file)

table = soup.findAll('table')[0]
rows = table.findAll('tr')

first_columns = []
third_columns = []
for row in rows[1:]:
    first_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[0])
    third_columns.append(row.findAll('td')[2])

for first, third in zip(first_columns, third_columns):
    print(first.text, third.text)
```

Comment: thank you for the help looks like its what i need but i keep getting 
IndexError: list index out of range errors
at line 8 : table = soup.findAll('table')[0]

Comment: @user3498833 I tested the code above i wrote. It does not give errors

Answer (score 0):

You may find htql easier for this:

```
import htql
results=htql.query(html_data, "<table>1.<tr> {c1=<td>1:tx; c4=<td>4:tx } ");
```